# Create collapsible elements dynamically with nested listview from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create a list of collapsible elements with listview inside each of them.
This is the json data i am using.

```
[
   {
      "productId":1,
      "name":"Coffee",
      "baseprice":2.00,
      "productoption":[
         {
            "productOptionId":1,
            "topping":"honeymustard",
            "baseprice":0.30
         },
         {
            "productOptionId":2,
            "topping":"barbeque",
            "baseprice":0.50
         },
         {
            "productOptionId":3,
            "topping":"whipcream",
            "baseprice":0.50
         }
      ],
      "productSubOption":[
         {
            "productSubOptionId":1,
            "size":"Small",
            "baseprice":0.50
         },
         {
            "productSubOptionId":2,
            "size":"Medium",
            "baseprice":0.50
         },
         {
            "productSubOptionId":3,
            "size":"Large",
            "baseprice":0.50
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "productId":2,
      "name":"Burger",
      "baseprice":2.00,
      "productoption":[
         {
            "productOptionId":4,
            "topping":"mayo",
            "baseprice":0.50
         },
         {
            "productOptionId":5,
            "topping":"onion",
            "baseprice":0.50
         }
      ],
      "productSubOption":[
         {
            "productSubOptionId":4,
            "size":"Small",
            "baseprice":0.50
         },
         {
            "productSubOptionId":5,
            "size":"Medium",
            "baseprice":0.50
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I did this for creating collapsible list. But my listview does not show inside of the collapsible. I am new to jquery so not sure what is wrong. I looked at many posts but it is hard to figure out.

```
function getMenuForVendor(data,status,jqxhr){
    var list = "";
    var menu = data;
        var menulistitem = createList(menu);

    $(document).on('pageshow','#Menu',function(){
        alert('hi from pageshow');
        $('#menu-content').append(menulistitem);
        $('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
        $('div ul').trigger('create');
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
}

function createList(menudata){
    var html = [];
    $.each(menudata,function(i,val){
        html.push('<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" data-id='+val.productId+'><h3>'+val.name+'</h3><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>');
        $.each(val.productoption,function(i,val){
            html.push('<li class="row">'+val.topping+'</li>');
        });
        html.push('</div>');
    });
return html;
}
```

When i press the back button on my phone and again come to the Menu page the number of collapsibles increase (repeatedly get appended). How to solve it?
Also, if i click the list item inside collapsible then I want to get a new page with checkboxes for productSubOptions. Please guide.

Comment: `$("#menu-content").empty()` before adding more items, because you're using `pageshow`. Items will be added whenever page is shown. Alternatively, use `pageinit` or `pagecreate` to append items once only.

Comment: if i use page create and i use $.mobile.pagechange to get to Menu page then the elements dont appear on it for some reason. it is working only if i do page show

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: This is 1.4.0 jquery mobile version

Comment: Check this Angular directive out http://mohsenweb.com/json-formatter/dist/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In createList instead of an array, just build a string of HTML (make sure you don't close the UL before adding the LIs):

```
function createList(menudata){
    var html = '';
    $.each(menudata,function(i,val){
        html += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" data-id='+val.productId+'><h3>'+val.name+'</h3><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
        $.each(val.productoption,function(i,val){
            html += '<li class="row">'+val.topping+'</li>';
        });
        html += '</ul></div>';
    });
    return html;
}
```

Then in pagecreate or pageshow:

```
var menulistitem = createList(data);
$('#menu-content').empty().append(menulistitem);
$('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
$('div ul').listview();
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5qe6g/1/)**